# Add close button using icon in popup

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am new to HTML, CSS... I am creating a custom Popup and it's working properly but I want to be able to close the popup using an icon.

You can find my code below. My custom popup just adds a cross icon at the right side top corner in this popup.

```css
/* Popup container - can be anything you want */

.popup {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
}


/* The actual popup */

.popup .popuptext {
  visibility: hidden;
  width: 160px;
  background-color: #555;
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
  border-radius: 6px;
  padding: 8px 0;
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -80px;
  margin-top: 10px;
}

.popup .show {
  visibility: visible;
  -webkit-animation: fadeIn 1s;
  animation: fadeIn 1s;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
</head>

<body style="text-align:center">

  <h2>Popup</h2>
  <a href="#" onclick="myFunction()">Click</a>
  <div class="popup">
    <span class="popuptext" id="myPopup">
       <input type="text" size="16"/>
      </span>
  </div>
  <script>
    // When the user clicks on div, open the popup
    function myFunction() {
      var popup = document.getElementById("myPopup");
      popup.classList.toggle("show");
    }
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

First you need to add close icon  and call same `toggle` function on close `X` icon:

```js
// When the user clicks on div, open the popup
function myFunction() {
  var popup = document.getElementById("myPopup");
  popup.classList.toggle("show");
}
```

```css
/* Popup container - can be anything you want */

.popup {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
}
.close{
   cursor:pointer;
text-align:right;
display:block;
padding:10px;
}

/* The actual popup */

.popup .popuptext {
  visibility: hidden;
  width: 160px;
  background-color: #555;
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
  border-radius: 6px;
  padding: 8px 0;
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -80px;
  margin-top: 10px;
}

.popup .show {
  visibility: visible;
  -webkit-animation: fadeIn 1s;
  animation: fadeIn 1s;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>

</head>

<body style="text-align:center">

  <h2>Popup</h2>
  <a href="#" onclick="myFunction()">Click</a>
  <div class="popup">

    <div class="popuptext" id="myPopup">
      <span class="close" onclick="myFunction()">X</span>
      <input type="text" size="16" />
    </div>
  </div>

</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You just simply need to add a `div` or `span` or maybe an anchor tag `a` that has your close button and then execute the same function, i.e., `myFunction()`, when that button is clicked. It is done in the following code, its not perfect by CSS, but it works nicely:

```css
/* Popup container - can be anything you want */

.popup {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
}


/* The actual popup */

.popup .popuptext {
  visibility: hidden;
  width: 160px;
  background-color: #555;
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
  border-radius: 6px;
  padding: 8px 0;
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -80px;
  margin-top: 10px;
}

.popup .show {
  visibility: visible;
  -webkit-animation: fadeIn 1s;
  animation: fadeIn 1s;
}

.close-button {
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  top: -10px;
  background: #555;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
</head>

<body style="text-align:center">

  <h2>Popup</h2>
  <a href="#" onclick="myFunction()">Click</a>
  <div class="popup">
    <span class="popuptext" id="myPopup">
       <div class="close-button" onclick="myFunction();">x</div>
       <input type="text" size="16"/>
      </span>
  </div>
  <script>
    // When the user clicks on div, open the popup
    function myFunction() {
      var popup = document.getElementById("myPopup");
      popup.classList.toggle("show");
    }
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```